# Python BeautifulSoup - just Text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape from the web some information like price etc. and then I want to put it into table, but my output is:

```
['789\xa0€']
['Na sklade > 5\xa0ks']
```

on the website, it is:

```
<span>789&nbsp;€</span>
<span>5&nbspks</span>
```

I want to get rid of that &nbsp (or \n) but how?

Comment: add the code you have tried also post the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [46]: import unicodedata

In [47]: a = ['789\xa0€','Na sklade > 5\xa0ks']

In [48]: unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", a[1])
Out[48]: 'Na sklade > 5 ks'

In [49]: unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", a[0])
Out[49]: '789 €'
```